# Can't click on anything after presenting UIAlertController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I present a `UIAlerController` from an extra window's root view controller in AppDelegate.

```
//AppDelegate.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *alertWindow;

//SomeViewController.m
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
 UIAlertAction* action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction* a){[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];});             
 [alert addAction:action];

 appDelegate.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
 appDelegate.alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 appDelegate.alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
 [appDelegate.alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
 [appDelegate.alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
```

When this `UIAlertController` dismisses, I can't interact with anything on the screen anymore.. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Because your `alertWindow` is still there on top of your app getting the touch events

Comment: Why do you create a whole new window just to show the alert?

Comment: @rmaddy because I'm trying to keep the popup open until it is dismissed by  the user. When I present the popup with a `rootviewcontroller`, it disappears as my view controller presents other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to dismiss the alert controller. It will be dismissed when the alert action's handler is called.

Only in the handler hide or destroy the alertWindow.

Here try this:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    appDelegate.alertWindow.hidden = YES;
    appDelegate.alertWindow = nil;
}];


                         [alert addAction:alertAction];
                         appDelegate.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
                         appDelegate.alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
                         appDelegate.alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
[appDelegate.alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[appDelegate.alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this by adding this into the handler for the button:

```
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
appDelegate.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
```

Not sure if this is the right fix for it, but it gets the job done for now... Would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: You do not want to set the window level like that.

Comment: You didn't need to set the level before showing the other window. And you don't want your main window higher than the alert level. The answer by BamBam is correct. Hide and remove the alert window and leave your main window at its default level.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the line:

```
appDelegate.alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
```

Your UIAlertController is under the alertWindow and not receiving touches.